# apps scripts edit log

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the Google Sheets application, I added a new tab "Edit Log" to display the logs. The logs are displayed when I edit the form in Google Sheets. How can I make them show logs when I edit directly an application ---> main.JS.html that changes sheet parameters?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var user = e.user;
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  var newValue = e.value;
  var sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var logSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Edit Log");
  if (logSheet == null) {
    logSheet = e.source.insertSheet("Edit Log");
    logSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "User", "Cell", "Old Value", "New Value", "Sheet Name"]);
  }
  logSheet.appendRow([timestamp, user, cell, oldValue, newValue, sheetName]);
}
```

code edits to make editing work

Comment: In a few words.  You can't because onEdit only triggers on userEdits.  But you can write to the log yourself from the html via - [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)